# pcolormesh: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'spines'

Tags: matplotlib, cartopy

I want to build a figure showing 6 rasters (.tif) using pcolormesh. I calculated lat lon coordinates from the UTM coordinates using rasterio

```
with rio.open(T_files[0]) as r:
T0 = r.transform
p1 = Proj(r.crs)
T = r.read()
Turbidity = r.read(1)

cols, rows = np.meshgrid(np.arange(T.shape[2]), np.arange(T.shape[1]))

T1 = T0*Affine.translation(0.5,0.5)
rc2en = lambda r, c: (c, r)*T1

eastings, northings = np.vectorize(rc2en, otypes=[np.float, np.float])(rows, cols)

p2 = Proj(proj='latlong', datum='WGS84')
longs_CD, lats_CD = transform(p1, p2, eastings, northings)
```

This piece of code was used for each raster since they all have slightly different dimensions due to different satellite orbits. I tried to plot the figure afterwards using

```
fig1 = plt.figure(figsize=(30, 10), dpi=150)
fig1.patch.set_alpha(1)
#fig.add_subplot(ROW,COLUMN,POSITION)
ax0 = plt.subplot(131, projection=ccrs.Mercator())
ax1 = plt.subplot(132, projection=ccrs.Mercator())
ax2 = plt.subplot(133, projection=ccrs.Mercator())
ax3 = plt.subplot(231, projection=ccrs.Mercator())
ax4 = plt.subplot(232, projection=ccrs.Mercator())
ax5 = plt.subplot(233, projection=ccrs.Mercator())

f0 = ax0.pcolormesh(longs_CD, lats_CD, np.ma.masked_invalid(TCD), 
                    shading='auto', transform = ccrs.PlateCarree(),
                    vmin=1, vmax=200, cmap=plt.cm.rainbow, norm=colors.LogNorm(vmin=1, vmax=200))
    
f1 = ax1.pcolormesh(longs_ND, lats_ND, np.ma.masked_invalid(TND), 
                    shading='auto', transform = ccrs.PlateCarree(),
                    vmin=1, vmax=200, cmap=plt.cm.rainbow, norm=colors.LogNorm(vmin=1, vmax=200))

f2 = ax2.pcolormesh(longs_ED, lats_ED, np.ma.masked_invalid(TED), 
                    shading='auto', transform = ccrs.PlateCarree(),
                    vmin=1, vmax=200, cmap=plt.cm.rainbow, norm=colors.LogNorm(vmin=1, vmax=200))

f3 = ax3.pcolormesh(longs_CK, lats_CK, np.ma.masked_invalid(TCK), 
                    shading='auto', transform = ccrs.PlateCarree(),
                    vmin=1, vmax=200, cmap=plt.cm.rainbow, norm=colors.LogNorm(vmin=1, vmax=200))

f4 = ax4.pcolormesh(longs_NK, lats_NK, np.ma.masked_invalid(TNK), 
                    shading='auto', transform = ccrs.PlateCarree(),
                    vmin=1, vmax=200, cmap=plt.cm.rainbow, norm=colors.LogNorm(vmin=1, vmax=200))

f5 = ax5.pcolormesh(longs_EK, lats_EK, np.ma.masked_invalid(TEK), 
                    shading='auto', transform = ccrs.PlateCarree(),
                    vmin=1, vmax=200, cmap=plt.cm.rainbow, norm=colors.LogNorm(vmin=1, vmax=200))

g1 = ax0.gridlines(draw_labels = True)
g1.ylabels_right = None
g1.xlabels_bottom = None
g1.xlabel_style = {'size': 20, 'color': 'k'}
g1.ylabel_style = {'size': 20, 'color': 'k'}

g1 = ax1.gridlines(draw_labels = True)
g1.ylabels_left = None
g1.xlabels_bottom = None
g1.xlabel_style = {'size': 20, 'color': 'k'}
g1.ylabel_style = {'size': 20, 'color': 'k'}

g1 = ax2.gridlines(draw_labels = True)
g1.ylabels_left = None
g1.xlabels_bottom = None
g1.xlabel_style = {'size': 20, 'color': 'k'}
g1.ylabel_style = {'size': 20, 'color': 'k'}

g1 = ax3.gridlines(draw_labels = True)
g1.ylabels_left = None
g1.xlabels_bottom = None
g1.xlabel_style = {'size': 20, 'color': 'k'}
g1.ylabel_style = {'size': 20, 'color': 'k'}

g1 = ax4.gridlines(draw_labels = True)
g1.ylabels_left = None
g1.xlabels_bottom = None
g1.xlabel_style = {'size': 20, 'color': 'k'}
g1.ylabel_style = {'size': 20, 'color': 'k'}

g1 = ax5.gridlines(draw_labels = True)
g1.ylabels_left = None
g1.xlabels_bottom = None
g1.xlabel_style = {'size': 20, 'color': 'k'}
g1.ylabel_style = {'size': 20, 'color': 'k'}

cb1 = fig1.colorbar(f1, orientation="horizontal", fraction=0.05, pad=0.07)
cb1.set_label('mean Turbidity [FNU]', fontsize=18)
cb1.tick_params(labelsize=20)
 
plt.show()
plt.clf()
```

Similar code snippets run usually fine for me, but this time an error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'spines'. I am pretty sure this is easy to fix but i cant figure it out. This is the complete error message

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-ced9235ef932> in <module>
     11 f0 = ax0.pcolormesh(longs_CD, lats_CD, np.ma.masked_invalid(TCD), 
     12                     shading='auto', transform = ccrs.PlateCarree(),
---> 13                     vmin=1, vmax=200, cmap=plt.cm.rainbow, norm=colors.LogNorm(vmin=1, vmax=200))
     14 
     15 f1 = ax1.pcolormesh(longs_ND, lats_ND, np.ma.masked_invalid(TND), 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cartopy\mpl\geoaxes.py in wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    308 
    309         kwargs['transform'] = transform
--> 310         return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
    311     return wrapper
    312 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cartopy\mpl\geoaxes.py in pcolormesh(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1559 
   1560         """
-> 1561         result = self._pcolormesh_patched(*args, **kwargs)
   1562         self.autoscale_view()
   1563         return result

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cartopy\mpl\geoaxes.py in _pcolormesh_patched(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1657         self.update_datalim(corners)
   1658         self.add_collection(collection)
-> 1659         self.autoscale_view()
   1660 
   1661         ########################

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cartopy\mpl\geoaxes.py in autoscale_view(self, tight, scalex, scaley)
    853     def autoscale_view(self, tight=None, scalex=True, scaley=True):
    854         matplotlib.axes.Axes.autoscale_view(self, tight=tight,
--> 855                                             scalex=scalex, scaley=scaley)
    856         # Limit the resulting bounds to valid area.
    857         if scalex and self._autoscaleXon:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py in autoscale_view(self, tight, scalex, scaley)
   2579         handle_single_axis(
   2580             scalex, self._autoscaleXon, self._shared_x_axes, 'intervalx',
-> 2581             'minposx', self.xaxis, self._xmargin, x_stickies, self.set_xbound)
   2582         handle_single_axis(
   2583             scaley, self._autoscaleYon, self._shared_y_axes, 'intervaly',

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py in handle_single_axis(scale, autoscaleon, shared_axes, interval, minpos, axis, margin, stickies, set_bound)
   2574             if not self._tight:
   2575                 x0, x1 = locator.view_limits(x0, x1)
-> 2576             set_bound(x0, x1)
   2577             # End of definition of internal function 'handle_single_axis'.
   2578 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py in set_xbound(self, lower, upper)
   3170         self.set_xlim(sorted((lower, upper),
   3171                              reverse=bool(self.xaxis_inverted())),
-> 3172                       auto=None)
   3173 
   3174     def get_xlim(self):

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py in set_xlim(self, left, right, emit, auto, xmin, xmax)
   3338 
   3339         if emit:
-> 3340             self.callbacks.process('xlim_changed', self)
   3341             # Call all of the other x-axes that are shared with this one
   3342             for other in self._shared_x_axes.get_siblings(self):

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py in process(self, s, *args, **kwargs)
    227                 except Exception as exc:
    228                     if self.exception_handler is not None:
--> 229                         self.exception_handler(exc)
    230                     else:
    231                         raise

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py in _exception_printer(exc)
     79 def _exception_printer(exc):
     80     if _get_running_interactive_framework() in ["headless", None]:
---> 81         raise exc
     82     else:
     83         traceback.print_exc()

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py in process(self, s, *args, **kwargs)
    222             if func is not None:
    223                 try:
--> 224                     func(*args, **kwargs)
    225                 # this does not capture KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit,
    226                 # and GeneratorExit

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cartopy\mpl\geoaxes.py in _trigger_patch_reclip(event)
   2060     axes = event.axes
   2061     # trigger the outline and background patches to be re-clipped
-> 2062     axes.spines['geo'].stale = True
   2063     axes.patch.stale = True

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'spines'
```

Comment: which line in particular produces that error. It would probably be more helpful if you paste the whole traceback here

Comment: no problem, i added the full error message from my jupyter notebook

Comment: Do simple cartopy tests work?  My assumption is that you have a crossed cartopy and matplotlib install and cartopy is simply broken.

Comment: i can do easy catopy plots with no problem. re-installing the package resolves in the same eroor as before